# Is it possible my mistake here to be because of the date format?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date-formatting

Ok here is my problem. I want to make a query which takes all rows of my table where the date given by the user into my form doesn't stack at all.

I have a form with two dates fields:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Ha</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="cars.php">
        <fieldset>
                    <legend>Rent A Car</legend>
            <div class='ddate'><p>Дата на наемане:<input type="date" id="datepicker" name="d1"></p></div>
                        <div class='ddate'><p>Дата на връщане:<input type="date" id="datepicker1" name="d2"></p></div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Провери" name="submit"/>
                </fieldset> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And i have a query where i think the problem is the date format.

```
<?php
//Connection
include "connect.php";
    $d1 = $_POST['d1'];
    $d2 = $_POST['d2'];
//Query
    $sql = "SELECT cars.brand,cars.model,cars.reg_num,cars.horse_powers,cars.color FROM cars INNER JOIN clients_cars ON cars.id=clients_cars.cars_id WHERE cars.id IN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT clients_cars.cars_id FROM clients_cars WHERE (rent_date not between '$d1' AND '$d2') AND (return_date not between '$d1' AND '$d2') AND ((return_date < '$d1') OR (rent_date > '$d2')))"; 

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    echo mysqli_error($con);
    while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $brand = $row['brand'];
        $model = $row['model'];
        $reg_num = $row['reg_num'];
        $horse_powers = $row['horse_powers'];
        $color = $row['color'];

        echo $brand;

    }
?>
```

When i submit this query it takes me out all rows of the column "brand" no matter of the parameters i choosed into the date input fields.

What i should do ? Maybe i need to change the date types ? Or i dont know... it looks like the query is right and its work but it doesn't care about the $d1 and $d2 pls someone can help me ?

Comment: Maybe you need to set the date format to `yyyy-mm-dd`. Do you get it like `mm-dd-yy` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumes that your input are coming in the format `mm/dd/yyyy.`
You need to convert into mysql format with `date(`) and `strtotime`.

```
$d1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['d1']));
$d2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['d2']));
```

Comment: Done ! Thank your very much mate :) I tried to make the sql table format same as the input format and there was my mistake. It should be your way. The input format to the same as the table one and i dont need to change the format into my table.